# Sharing / Twitter not working as usual

Tags: ios, twitter

When trying to share a picture on Twitter from an iOS app (of mine) -- already on the appStore -- I keep getting this message:

[image]

But the reality is that I am already logged in to a Twitter account.
I can switch to the Twitter app, confirm that I am logged in and come back to the current app.

Am I doing something the wrong way with Twitter?
Or is possible that something is not working with the app itself?

I need to say that this kind of sharing used to work without problems.
So this might be due to some recent change in the iOS.

Comment: iOS 11 removed social sharing with Twitter. Does your app use Twitter Kit 3?

Comment: Honestly I don't remember (I don't think so), this is an app I released quite a while ago. I suppose we have other ways to share on Twitter from an iOS app?

Comment: If the Twitter app is installed you should be able to use the regular iOS share sheet.

Comment: Good idea that I would be happy to try. But for some reason that I do not know, even though I have Twitter installed, it does not appear in the list of regular iOS share sheet.